# Error securing Tibco EMS

Tags: tibco-ems

I just finished installing Tibco EMS on a server that is already running on the old version of tibco. Installation was successful ant it started up properly. But i am having a bit of issues trying to secure the EMS server. I am getting the error below after i entered the default user;

```
/prov_uat/npsdev1/test/prov/New_Tibco/tibco/ems/8.2/bin> ./tibemsadmin connect

TIBCO Enterprise Message Service Administration Tool.
Copyright 2003-2015 by TIBCO Software Inc.
All rights reserved.

Version 8.2.1 V4 2/1/2015

Login name (admin): admin
Password:
Failed connect to 'connect': error=17, message=Invalid hostname
```

Anyone with the idea on how to resolve this...

Answer (score 2):

To connect to an EMS instance through the admin utility, you just have to call it. It does not need a separate "connect" operation.

```
$ ./tibemsadmin

TIBCO Enterprise Message Service Administration Tool.
Copyright 2003-2013 by TIBCO Software Inc.
All rights reserved.

Version 8.0.0 V9 6/7/2013

Type 'help' for commands help, 'exit' to exit:
```

If your server is not listening on the default port on localhost you can further specify the address with "-server".

```
./tibemsadmin -server "tcp://myhost:7222"
```

Comment: Thanks Jens! The EMS server was started up and running properly. But, the connection needed to be secure... Hence with the "./tibemsadmin connect" Kindly provide me more insight pls...

Comment: There is no "./tibemsadmin connect", what you are trying is an invalid invoke of the admin utillity. In your case, the utility uses the "connect" parameter as the server adress url, which is always not correct, since this is not an url.

Answer (score 0):

run tibemsadmin without arguments to be talking to the local EMS server.
'connect' is a command within tibemsadmin, not a command line option.